# I am trying to automate gmail login using selenium . But in whichever browser I try I get the Err "This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more"

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying automate the login to gmail process using selenium using Javascript. I get the error "This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in."

I have tried different Browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) all throw the same error.
I did a some investigation and disbled chrome://flags "Site isolation". Nothing seems to work. My tests were working in Chrome version 15.x and now in version 117.0.5938.88, nothing seems to work . Any help here would be Really Appreciated.

````
driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('firefox')
.build();

driver.get('https://www.gmail.com')
sleep(20000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys("prodkia2.aus");
sleep(5000); // //*[@id="identifierId"]

driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span')).click();```
````

Comment: Its one of Google's validation error responses. Look into "Two Factor Authentication"

Comment: I have not enabled any authentication in the test gmail account that I am using in my automation.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB

Try this, Google no longer supports "Enable less secure login", I used this 16 digit pass code to authenticate with gmail services before and it worked. But let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: The research @RamuNarasinga provided via the link says, quote "App passwords can only be used with accounts that have 2-Step Verification turned on". https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB